# It is possible to merge two separate DBs (e.g. db0, db1) running in one single Redis instance (6379) into one single DB (db0)?

Tags: redis

Cannot find an easy solution. Migrate command seems not to be the solution.
Persist, delete them, create one single db and load the backup maybe?

Answer (score 3):

There is the [`SWAPDB`](https://redis.io/commands/swapdb) that allows you to swap them.

There is no out-of-the-box support for merging, since there may be conflicts. If there are two keys with the same name on both databases, it needs to be resolved.

The [`MOVE`](https://redis.io/commands/move) commands allows you to move a key from the current DB to a destination DB.

You can use a combination of [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) and `MOVE` to get the merge done. I suggest `SCAN` instead of `KEYS` because if you're doing this in production, you don't want to block the server for long periods of time.

Here a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to do this:

```
local result = redis.call('SCAN', ARGV[1])
local conflict = {}
local moved = {}
for _,key in ipairs(result[2]) do
    if redis.call('MOVE', key, ARGV[2]) == 0 then
        table.insert(conflict, key)
    else
        table.insert(moved, key)
    end
end
result[2] = conflict
result[3] = moved
return result
```

You call this with parameters:

- numkeys: `0`
- ARGV[1]: the cursor for `SCAN`, initially `0`.
- ARGV[2]: the destination database. E.g. `2`

Make sure to [`SELECT`](https://redis.io/commands/select) the source database first.

Here a example first run:

```
> EVAL "local result = redis.call('SCAN', ARGV[1]) \n local conflict = {} \n local moved = {} \n for _,key in ipairs(result[2]) do \n     if redis.call('MOVE', key, ARGV[2]) == 0 then \n         table.insert(conflict, key) \n else \n     table.insert(moved, key) \n     end \n end \n result[2] = conflict \n result[3] = moved \n return result" 0 0 2
1) "56"
2) 1) "key:6"
3) 1) "key:79"
   2) "key:96"
   3) "key:44"
   4) "key:91"
   5) "key:82"
   6) "key:25"
   7) "key:22"
   8) "key:41"
   9) "key:73"
```

Here the `SCAN` found 10 keys, returned next cursor `56`. `key:6` was found on the destination, so it was not moved. The third entry is the list of keys actually moved.

As with `SCAN`, you need to call multiple times until the return cursor is `0`. And remember added keys in between `SCAN` calls may or may not be returned.

You can modify the Lua script to:

- Implement your merge logic, like delete the key on the destination and then move, and still report the deleted key on the destination separately.
- Change `SCAN` to use a larger `COUNT` if you want more keys covered by call.
- Replace `SCAN` with `KEYS` to do it on one go.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: Happy to help, please accept the answer if you find it fully addresses your question